# How to write Tensorboard event file by using just protobufs in C++?

Tags: tensorflow, protocol-buffers, tensorboard

Using C++ I was able to write an event file containing a graphdef without a problem.  I used EventsWriter::WriterEvent() API.   I looked great on TensorBoard.

After a deep dive, I found code in tensorflow.core.util, tensorflow.core.platform, and tensorflow.core.lib.io that wraps the tensorflow::Event in a record in this format: length, masked CRC of length, data, masked CRC of data.  ([github source here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/lib/io/record_writer.cc))

But the problem is that I do not want to statically link to the contrib TensorFlow library with my app.  Instead, I'd like to make my app lightweight and decoupled from the library by using my local protoc-compiled headers (*.pb.h) and sources (*.pb.c).

I am able to create an event file using protobufs, but they are not visualized on TensorBoard.  While using the debugger on Tensorboard source, I see an DataLossError exception when launching Tensorboard here: tensorboard/backend/event_processing/event_file_loader.py.  The DataLossError exception is likely due to the fact that the tensorflow::Event is not wrapped as described above.

If you or anyone knows a strategy to write TB-compatible event files in C++ without using the contrib tensorflow library, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

So the solution is to wrap each Event record with these fours fields:

1. uint64    (length)
2. uint32    (masked crc of length)
3. byte      (data[length])
4. uint32    (masked crc of data)

See WriteRecord() [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/lib/io/record_writer.cc)